# Cannot read property object reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, axios

I just have to extract the data

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import CoinsConvert from '../data/data'
import '../style/bootstrap.min.css';


class BoxInfo extends Component{

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      dataC:{}
    }

  }
  componentWillMount(){
        let code=CoinsConvert[this.props.match.params.coin_url];
        axios.get(`https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshotfullbyid/?id=${code}`)
        .then(da=>this.setState({dataC:da.data})).catch(()=>{console.error()})
  }
 render(){
   let dataC=this.state.dataC;
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className="panel panel-default text-center"  >
        <div className="panel-heading" >{ dataC.Data.General.H1Text}</div>
        <div className="panel-body "><img className="img-rounded"  width="500" height="500" src={""} /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
   }
}
```

[image]

Example json: [cryptocompare](https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinsnapshotfullbyid/?id=5031)

Comment: try `dataC.General.H1Text` instead of `dataC.Data.General.H1Text`

Comment: what do you get when you do `console.log(this.state.dataC)`  just to see the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple one, api calls are asynchronous so `this.state.dataC` will be `{}` until you get the api response.

During first rendering when you try to access:

`this.state.dataC.Data` it will be **undefined** and when you try to access any value of `undefined` it will throw the error:

> Can't read property XYZ of undefined.

**Solution:**

Put the check on data, once you get the data then only render then ui.

Like this:

```
render(){

   let dataC=this.state.dataC;
   if(!Object.keys(dataC)) return null;

   return (
       ....
   )
}
```

You can also put the check on each value, Like this:

```
{ dataC.Data && dataC.Data.General && dataC.Data.General.H1Text}
```

**Suggestion:**

Instead of making the api call inside **[componentWillMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount)**, write it inside **[componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)**.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is due to the fact that you set `dataC` as a result of async data fetching. Therefore `componentWillMount` will complete, then `render` will be called, and note! - at this point the data might not still be fetched - so in render your dataC is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should get async data only in `componentDidMount` method [DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)
Another thing that i think may cause a problem, with this line:

```
this.setState({dataC:da.data})
```

You actually already accessed the `data` property.
In your render method you should do this:

```
dataC.General.H1Text
```

Instead of this:

```
dataC.Data.General.H1Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Use optional chaining :

const data = somevalue;
console.log(data?.value);